# Oracle db get values between specific dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this `DATETIME` field in my oracle database shown in the image

[image]

I'm trying to make a query which returns something between specific dates but this query returns nothing.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tbl_meter 
 WHERE TO_DATE(DATETIME,'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_meter WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN '15/01/2014' AND '07/01/2014'
```

[image]

Comment: What values are you passing in %s ? What is data type of DATETIME column?

Comment: Which datatype has that `datetime` column? If it is a `DATE` column, the `like`operator does not make any sense (plus applying `to_date()` on a `date` column to convert it to a `date` doesn't make sense)

Comment: %s -> dd/mm/yyyy format. And DATETIME is a timestamp in database

Comment: Applying `to_date()` on a `timestamp` column is totally useless. `to_date()` converts a string into a date. When you apply it on a `timestamp` column, the timestamp first gets converted into a string (subject to implicit data type conversion based on various NLS settings) which then gets converted back to a `date` value. Simply use `where datetime between %1 and %2` and you should be fine. You maybe want to apply the `trunc()` function on the value to remove the time part.

Comment: Trying where datetime between %1 and %s2 returns nothing. If you can see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_meter 
WHERE TRUNC(DATETIME) BETWEEN to_date('%s','DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('%s','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Asssuming `DATETIME` is of `DATE` data type.

If it is of `TIMESTAMP` datatype then,

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_meter 
WHERE TRUNC(CAST(DATETIME AS DATE)) BETWEEN to_date('%s','DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('%s','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

If it is `VARCHAR`, then

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_meter 
WHERE TRUNC(To_DATE(DATETIME,'Dd/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF6')) BETWEEN to_date('%s','DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('%s','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: Your TIMESTAMP query has a syntax error. ora-00907 missing parantesis

Comment: Does first %s always have to be smaller then the second %s? Otherwise query returns empty

Comment: Uhm, interesting fact. In mySQL it doesn't matter which one is smaller.

Comment: Yup, Oracle optimzer converts, between into >= and <= respectively for the values. It doesnt validate which of the parameter is bigger! May be MySQL is designed to handle that..

Comment: You don't need to explicitly `cast` in the second version, but it doesn't hurt and I guess spells out what's happening. ([The value returned is always of data type DATE, even if you specify a different datetime data type for date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm)).

Comment: Yes Alex, But i was not sure, if it works for all Oracle versions.! So to be foolproof, Made the casting explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the same parameter twice. I expect you to have

```
select * 
from   tbl_meter 
where  to_date(datetime, 'DD/MM/YYYY') between to_date('%s1', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('%s2', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: %s specifies a string variable is expected. I pass parameters to %s

Comment: What are the value(s) for %s then? If %s is a string, shouldn't you do to_date('%s') then?

Comment: value(s) for %s is something like 17/10/2013 and 19/11/2013 but those values comes from JSON as strings

Comment: If you write this query out (without using parameters), does it work then? If so, this is a program error. If not, you have to take a look at the SQL expression.

Comment: It returns empty in pl/sql without using parameters if you can see my edit

Comment: It looks like you are comparing strings now. use to_date(...) for datetime, and the values in the between.

Comment: Value I pass %1 and %2 are strings but in db, format is timestamp, that's where it gets confusing for me.

Comment: Sorry, to much copy/paste. Try again.

Comment: Yeah, yours also work but above answer was faster. I had no choice to accept. Thanks for all the help tho, really appriciate it

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_meter 
WHERE TO_DATE(DATETIME,'DD/MM/YYYY') >='%s' AND TO_DATE(DATETIME,'DD/MM/YYYY') <'%s'
```

Comment: There is no difference in the use of between or your query.

Comment: I know but it is just a thought we can give a try if it works